# Sails JS Two Queries second fails remove first

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sails.js

I'm not exactly sure how to describe my problem, that is why the title of this question is a bit confusing.
The situation is that if have an action inside a SailsJS Controller which should save data with the help of two different queries. My question is is there a nice and elegant way to remove the first entry if the second query fails (because the data of the two queries is connected)?

My current approach would be to use async auto. If there is an error I would check if one query was successful and remove it. But I can't stop thinking there must be a better way.

Bruno

**EDIT**
Here is my current code:

```
async.auto([
        user: function(callback) {
          User.create({
            mail: data.mail,
            password: data.password,
            device_id: data.device_id,
            own_number: data.own_number
          }).exec(callback);
        },
        contact: function(callback) {
          Contact.create({
            number: data.own_number,
            number_id: util.hash(data.own_number),
            soundlogo: null
          }).exec(callback);
        }
      ],
      function(error, results) {
        // check for error
        if(error){
          sails.log(error);

          // Check whether one was successful and remove it

          return res.json({errorMsg: error});
        }
```

Comment: Could you paste your current code, pls?

Comment: According to the code you pasted, `user` and `contact` are independent and none of the response params from `user` is being used in `contact`. So you can use `async.auto` and create entry in `contact` first and on success of that create entry in `user` table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple async series()

```
async.series([
    user: function(scb) {
      User.create({
        mail: data.mail,
        password: data.password,
        device_id: data.device_id,
        own_number: data.own_number
      }).exec(function(err, user){

         if(user){
            scb(null, user);
         }
         else{
            return res.json({errorMsg: "failed to create user!"});
            // scb("failed to create user!");
         }

      });
    },

    contact: function(scb) {
      Contact.create({
        number: data.own_number,
        number_id: util.hash(data.own_number),
        soundlogo: null
      })
      .exec(function(err, contact){

         if(user){
            scb(null, contact);
         }
         else{
            return res.json({errorMsg: "failed to create contact!"});
            // scb("failed to create contact!");
         }

      });
    }
],

function(error, results) {
    // check for error
    if(error){
    sails.log(error);

      // Check whether one was successful and remove it
      return res.json({errorMsg: error});
    }

});
```

you can use either direct sending response to client or use callback(err)